# Facebook registration plugin doesn't seem to be working on IE7/8

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

I'm using the registration plugin of facebook to manage registration of some site. It works in all browsers except in IE7/8.

In IE8, it gives some javascript error like 
   `'tagName' is null or not an object  zRlOgpwX8LW.js, line 31 character 492`.

You can see below the whole html code of the page.
So far the only thing i manage to figure out is that the presence of "onvalidate" attribute generates the error. If i remove it, everything works just fine.

Did anyone else encountered this? How did you manage to fix it?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      FB.init({
        "appId": '<< my app id >>',
        "cookie": true,
        "xfbml": true
      });

      function check_username(form, cb) {
        $.getJSON('http://mysite/checkUsername?username=' + form.username+'&callback=?',
        function(response) {
          if (response.message == "ok") {
            cb();
          }

          cb({'username': response.message});
        }
        )
      }
    </script>

    <fb:registration redirect-uri="http://mysite/facebook-register-done?redirect="
      fields='[{"name":"name"},
        {"name":"first_name"},
        {"name":"last_name"},
        {"name":"email"},
        {"name":"location"},
        {"name":"birthday"},
        {"name":"username","description":"Username","type":"text"}]'
      onvalidate="check_username"></fb:registration>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, it would help to get the failing JS (`zRlOgpwX8LW.js`) to analyze it.

Comment: I've tried that. It's a minified js and i finally gave up re-arranging the code (and tools like SourceFormaX seem to only broke the code because of the regular expressions in the code, among other reasons). Anyway, it seems like a bug in custom validation on client side. There's already a bug report http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15236

Comment: Yes, this is a Facebook bug, please upvote it at: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15236 so that it can get fixed asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Facebook bug. Nothing you can do. Sorry! (we are working on it)

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15236

Answer (score 1):

Add an XML namespace to the `<html>` tag of your document. This is necessary for XFBML to work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

It also works with HTML5 if you use data-somename="somevalue" attributes on elements.

`<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`

Answer (score 0):

From FB bugracker

```
------- Comment #34 From Stephen Doyle 2011-08-03 10:46:10 PDT -------
This should now be resolved. Thanks for your patience.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the FB namespace attribute to html tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```